# optimize a Select

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

How can I optimize my select :

```
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Country
  FROM Customer
 WHERE (Country ="x" and Id ="y") 
    or (Country ="x1" and Id ="y1")
    or (Country ="x2" and Id ="y2")
    or (Country ="x3" and Id ="y3")
    or (Country ="x4" and Id ="y4")
    or (Country ="x5" and Id ="y5")
```

Comment: Probably the first step is figuring out what DBMS you're using.  You have both `mysql` and `oracle` tagged.

Comment: Then, add to your question your table create statement and also an output result of a execution plan of it.

Comment: Any index defined?

Comment: Optimize for execution time or typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest writing it using tuples:

```
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Country
FROM Customer c
WHERE (Country, id) in ( ('x', 'y'), ('x1', 'y1'), . . . )
```

(This should work in both MySQL and Oracle but not in all databases.)

Then the database should be able to readily use an index on `Customer(Country, Id)`.  It might be able to use that index with the original version, as well.